# Many Handlers, not every will be executed

Tags: android

My app gets data for map markers from a server. Everytime a new marker arrives, the map should be notified and add the marker. The server interaction runs in its own thread. Because the mapview depends on the main loop I need to use a Handler:

```
 notifyMap(Marker marker) {
     Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

     Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() { 
              map.addMarker(marker) }
          };

     handler.post(runnable);
 }
```

Now I've did a test and added 100 markers

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    noitfyMap(new Marker(getRandomPosition()));
```

where `randomPosition` is a function which produces random coordinates where the markers should be placed.

The problem is: after this test, not every will be added to the map.  From 100 Markers there are ~70 visible. The debugger says that the markerarray contains ~70 markers, too. 
So I think that android destroys threads if there are too much. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android doesn't destroy threads, but there are no threads being created in your code-  the handler is on the main thread.  At worst handler messages would be deleted, but even that isn't the case.

Also, there's a much better way to do what you're doing-  create all the positions, then send one message with an array of them.  Its always better to do one thread switch than 100.

Comment: great idea! And you are right: It's not the problem with the threads but with the notification. My code above was simplified. I used the observable from java utils. This seems to not to harmonize with many threads. As workaround I've override the setChanged method, so it returns always true. Now it works. Thanks!